# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumer is not part of an active group

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        myConsumer-in-0:
          destination: abcd
          binder: kafka
          content-type: application/json
          group: groupname
          consumer:
            autoStartup: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          configuration:
            sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
            security.protocol: SASL_SSL
          jaas:
            loginModule: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
  kafka:
    properties:
      bootstrap.servers: server:443
      sasl:
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="zasas" password="hasjashgasgh";
```

I am getting some times this exception

Consumer exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1815)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1180)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1045)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1492)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy260.commitSync(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$List
```

Setting max records

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myConsumer
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          configuration:
            sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
            security.protocol: SASL_SSL
            max.poll.records: 100
```

Comment: `>... it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.` Most likely you are taking too long to process the results of the poll. Either reduce `max.poll.records` or increase `max.poll.interval.ms` (or both).

Comment: @GaryRussell Thank you. I updated question, can you help me if the syntax is correct.

Comment: It looks ok, but you can confirm it by looking at the info log.

Comment: @GaryRussell This is correct. It printed in info logs Thank you